# How do I get backslash marker in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I was hoping for this Python 3.11 script to render `\` markers:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 4], marker='$\textbackslash$', c='b')
plt.show()
```

but it renders `-` instead. How do I get `\` or similar marker?

Comment: Try: `marker=r'$\backslash$'`

Comment: @Loocid It works. Thank you. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link provides all the supported mathtext symbols you can use:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/mathtext.html

For a backslash try `marker=r'$\backslash$'`